# How To Sort mongodb query results based on subdocuments

Tags: mongodb

i am having 2 documents in score collections(student)databases like below in mongodb database.

```
{ 
    id: 2, 
    type: 'newname', 
    subs: [
        { time: 20, val: 'b' },
        { time: 12, val: 'a' },
        { time: 30, val: 'c' }
    ] }, { 
    id: 1, 
    type: 'strs', 
    subs: [
        { time: 50, val: 'be' },
        { time: 1, val: 'ab' },
        { time: 20, val: 'cs' }
    ] }
```

How to construct a query to get the below result

```
{ 
    id: 1, 
    type: 'strs', 
    subs: [
        { time: 1, val: 'ab' },
        { time: 20, val: 'cs' },
        { time: 50, val: 'be' }
    ]
},
{ 
    id: 2, 
    type: 'newname', 
    subs: [
        { time: 12, val: 'a' },
        { time: 20, val: 'b' },
        { time: 30, val: 'c' }
    ]
}
```

ie: a query for find the documents based on time and have to sort the results on 2 criteria

1. by **id** ASC
2. by sub document **time** ASC

Comment: i need to do same , can you please share your solution ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `cursor.sort()` to sort on multiple fields (basically a combo) at the same time but I don't think it works when sorting on both a document and a subdocument field at the same time. 
If you were to sort on two different fields of the top document or on two different fields of a subdocument then it would be fine i guess.

So you can get a similar output using the [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) framework. All you have to do is basically break down the arrays of the `subs` field and then [sort](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) them.

You could do something like:

```
db.col.aggregate({$unwind:'subs'}, {$sort:{id:1,'subs.time':1}});
```

With the above code you should get an output similar to this:

```
 { 
    id: 1, 
    type: 'strs', 
    subs: 
        { time: 1, val: 'ab' }
},{ 
    id: 1, 
    type: 'strs', 
    subs: 
        { time: 20, val: 'cs' }
},{ 
    id: 1, 
    type: 'strs', 
    subs: 
        { time: 50, val: 'be' }
},{ 
    id: 2, 
    type: 'newname', 
    subs: 
        { time: 12, val: 'a' }
},{ 
    id: 2, 
    type: 'newname', 
    subs: 
        { time: 20, val: 'b' }
},{ 
    id: 2, 
    type: 'newname', 
    subs: 
        { time: 30, val: 'c' }
}
```

Comment: The intended solution was { 
    id: 1, 
    type: 'strs', 
    subs: [
        { time: 1, val: 'ab' },
        { time: 20, val: 'cs' },
        { time: 50, val: 'be' }
    ]
},
{ 
    id: 2, 
    type: 'newname', 
    subs: [
        { time: 12, val: 'a' },
        { time: 20, val: 'b' },
        { time: 30, val: 'c' }
    ]
}

Comment: Correct, it's been a while since I saw that, but you can group as a last step of the aggregation I wrote and use $addToSet to get the desired output. If you want, I can write the query...

Comment: @tzik Please write complete query to get intended solution. I need to do same

Comment: @tzik You can answer this question : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63378828/mongoose-query-to-sort-main-document-subdocument-by-particular-field]

Answer (score 3):

Strangely, MongoDB does not provide any method to sort sub documents by querying it. It seems you will have to update the natural sort order of the sub docs as shown below :

If these are the only 2 docs in your collection, write below query :

```
db.test.update( {}, {$push : {"subs" :{$each  : [] , $sort : {time : -1}}}})
```

and then run query to sort on ID itself :

```
db.test.find().sort({'id':1}).pretty()
```

You will get below output.

```
{                                                             

        "id" : 1,                                             
        "type" : "strs",                                      
        "subs" : [                                            
                {                                             
                        "time" : 50,                          
                        "val" : "be"                          
                },                                            
                {                                             
                        "time" : 20,                          
                        "val" : "cs"                          
                },                                            
                {                                             
                        "time" : 1,                           
                        "val" : "ab"                          
                }                                             
        ]                                                     
}                                                             
{                                                             

        "id" : 2,                                             
        "type" : "newname",                                   
        "subs" : [                                            
                {                                             
                        "time" : 30,                          
                        "val" : "c"                           
                },                                            
                {                                             
                        "time" : 20,                          
                        "val" : "b"                           
                },                                            
                {                                             
                        "time" : 12,                          
                        "val" : "a"                           
                }                                             
        ]                                                     
}
```

Hope it solves you situation. Below is the reference :

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/#sort-array-of-documents-by-a-field-in-the-documents

Answer (score 0):

It is possible when use in sequence `$unwind` > `$sort` > `$group` specialty for array,

- [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) deconstruct array `subs`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$subs" },
```

- [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html) `subs.time` in ascending *(1)* order

```
  { $sort: { "subs.time": 1 } },
```

- [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) by `id`, and re-construct `subs` array using `$push` objects and other fields remain using `$first`

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$id",
      id: { $first: "$id" },
      type: { $first: "$type" },
      subs: { $push: "$subs" }
    }
  },
```

- [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html) to hide `_id`

```
  { $project: { _id: 0 } },
```

- `$sort` by `id` in ascending order

```
  { $sort: { id: 1 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/E0inJpSTBM7)

Answer (score -2):

You can use `cursor.sort(sort)`

For Exapmle:

```
db.collection.find().sort( { 'id': 1 } )
```

to sort the results using id in ascending order.

For more details refer the following link.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/

Comment: How do i sort the sub documents which contains list items from that i need to sort the list based on inner key time in the list. thats what i needed most

Comment: i think sorting sub documents is not possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848814/sort-sub-documents-in-mongodb