# Mongoose Query To Sort Main Document & SubDocument by particular field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I having 3 documents.

```
 const designTypeSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    name : {
        type : String,
        trim: true,
        required : true,
    },
    image : {
        type : String,
        trim: true,
        required : true,
    },
    status: { 
        type : Boolean,
        default: true
    } 
}
);

const tagTypeSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    name : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
    },
    design_type :
    {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'DesignType',
    }
    ,
    order : {  //need to apply sorting for this field
        type : Number,
        trim: true,
    },
    status: { 
        type : Boolean,
        default: true
    }  } );


const TagSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    name : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
    },
    tag_type : {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'TagType',
    image : {
        type : String,
        trim: true,
    },
    order : { //need to apply sorting for this field
        type : Number,
    },
    status: { 
        type : Boolean,
        default: true
    } 
}, 
);
```

I need to apply sort on 2 fields, TagType.order & Tag.order.

TagType will be considered as main document , so first TagType should list by order field and then Tag will be subdocument and it should list by Tag.order field.

I tried below query :

```
TagType.aggregate(
      [
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "tags",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "tag_type",
            as: "tags",
          },
      },
      {
          $lookup: {
              from: "designtypes",
              localField: "design_type",
              foreignField: "_id",
              as: "designtype",
          }
        },
        {
          $project:
          {
            _id: 1,
            name: 1,
            tag_type: 1,
            order: 1,
            "designtype.name":1,
            "tags._id":1,
            "tags.name":1,
            "tags.image":1,
            "tags.order":1,
            totalTags: {$size: "$tags"},
          }
        },
        {
          $sort : { 
            "order": -1,
            'tags.order' : -1
          } 
        },
      ]
    ).exec(function(err, results) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      res.status(200).json({
          message: 'success',
          total: results.length,
          response: {
              data: results
          }
      })
    });
```

Using above query i am getting sorted result But its applying sorting on main document only, not on subdocuments(Tags). What i am missing in query to get desire result.

My question is related to this [6 years old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003908/how-to-sort-mongodb-query-results-based-on-subdocuments) :. But that question have not desire answer. So i posted new one.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently sort is not possible directly inside array objects,

You can do either 2 options,

- if you are getting data from lookup then use [lookup with pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup) it will allow to use `$sort` pipeline within match documents
- $unwind the array => $sort it => again $group it into array, [Refer SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63380113/8987128)

here you are using `$lookup`, instead of simple lookup you can use "$lookup with pipeline".

```
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "tags",
      as: "tags",
      let: { id: "$_id" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: { $eq: ["$$id", "$tag_type"] }
          }
        },
        {
          $sort: { order: -1 }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xxPzNgtLQzr)

---

Second possible solution: [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-vYuwM9NubM)

Comment: can you please add another possible solution using `unwind` ?

Comment: I have added an answer to that old question, and added link in this answer you can check.

Comment: Also added your solution in this answer.

Comment: ca you please take a look on this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63467246/mongoose-aggregate-query-for-getting-data-from-4-collection-by-id-and-group-by-a

Please check if you can help me ! Thanks