# Mongoose Aggregate Query For Getting Data From 4 Collection By Id and Group By Action

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have 3 collections

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    username : {
        type : String,
        trim: true
    },
    name : {
        type : String,
        trim: true
    },
    avatar : {
        type : String
    }
    last_seen: { 
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now 
    },
    status: { 
        type : Boolean,
        default: true
    }
})

const hsVideoSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
   name : {
        type : String,
        trim: true,
        required : true
    },
    url : {
        type : String,
        trim: true,
        required : true
    },
    uploadedBy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    status: { 
        type : Boolean,
        default: true
    } 
})

const fsVideoSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
   name : {
        type : String,
        trim: true,
        required : true
    },
    url : {
        type : String,
        trim: true,
        required : true
    },
    uploadedBy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    status: { 
        type : Boolean,
        default: true
    } 
})
```

Now, to keep user's action history, i created History Model as below :

```
const historySchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    user_id : {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    hs_videoId : {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'HsVideo',
        default: null
    },
    fs_videoId : {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'FsVideo',
        default: null
    },
    action : {
        type : String,
        trim: true,
        enum:['downloaded','viewed','liked','reported']
    }
})
```

So, i will add new record in history collection when user will perform any action. At a time, out of 2 fields (hs_videId & fs_videoId) one field will be null and another will have id of ref document. In history collection, there can be same hs_videId/fs_videId with different action ('downloaded','viewed','liked','reported').

I am looking for query to get user's history by passing user_id and get all video history array with 2 sub arrays : HsVideos and FsVideos. Both sub array should have action's sub-array, which will have complete details of video (name, url,uploadedBy(UserArray),status).

What query i should write to get desire result ?

Query i tried already :

```
User.aggregate([
            { $match: {_id : ObjectId('5f3a90110132e115db700201')} },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "histories",
                    as: "history",
                    pipeline: [
                        {
                            $match: {
                                user_id : ObjectId('5f3a90110132e115db700201')
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
            },
        ]).exec(function(err, results){
            if(err) console.log(err);                
            return res.status(200).json(results);
         })
```

Please help ! Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT : 1**

I am expecting below result :

```
[
  {
     "_id": ObjectId("5f3a90110132e115db700201"),
    "avatar": "default.png",
    "last_seen": ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
    "name": "John",
    "status": true,
    "username": "jony"
    "FsVideos": [
      {
        Viewed :[
          {
            "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
            "url": "http://example.com/video.mp4",
            "uploadedBy": {
                  "_id": ObjectId("5f3a90110132e115db700201"),
                  "avatar": "default.png",
                  "last_seen": ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                  "name": "A",
                  "status": true,
                  "username": "A"
            },
          },
          {
            "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
            "url": "http://example.com/video.mp4",
            "uploadedBy": {
                  "_id": ObjectId("5f3a90110132e115db700201"),
                  "avatar": "default.png",
                  "last_seen": ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                  "name": "A",
                  "status": true,
                  "username": "A"
            },
          }
        ],
        Downloaded :[
          {
            "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
            "url": "http://example.com/video.mp4",
            "uploadedBy": {
                  "_id": ObjectId("5f3a90110132e115db700201"),
                  "avatar": "default.png",
                  "last_seen": ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                  "name": "A",
                  "status": true,
                  "username": "A"
            },
          },
          {
            "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
            "url": "http://example.com/video.mp4",
            "uploadedBy": {
                  "_id": ObjectId("5f3a90110132e115db700201"),
                  "avatar": "default.png",
                  "last_seen": ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                  "name": "A",
                  "status": true,
                  "username": "A"
            },
          }
        ],
        Liked :[
          {
            "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
            "url": "http://example.com/video.mp4",
            "uploadedBy": {
                  "_id": ObjectId("5f3a90110132e115db700201"),
                  "avatar": "default.png",
                  "last_seen": ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                  "name": "A",
                  "status": true,
                  "username": "A"
            },
          },
          {
            "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
            "url": "http://example.com/video.mp4",
            "uploadedBy": {
                  "_id": ObjectId("5f3a90110132e115db700201"),
                  "avatar": "default.png",
                  "last_seen": ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                  "name": "A",
                  "status": true,
                  "username": "A"
            },
          }
        ],
        Reported :[
          {
            "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
            "url": "http://example.com/video.mp4",
            "uploadedBy": {
                  "_id": ObjectId("5f3a90110132e115db700201"),
                  "avatar": "default.png",
                  "last_seen": ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                  "name": "A",
                  "status": true,
                  "username": "A"
            },
          },
          {
            "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
            "url": "http://example.com/video.mp4",
            "uploadedBy": {
                  "_id": ObjectId("5f3a90110132e115db700201"),
                  "avatar": "default.png",
                  "last_seen": ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                  "name": "A",
                  "status": true,
                  "username": "A"
            },
          }
        ],
      }
    ],
    "HsVideos": [
      {
        Viewed :[
          {
            "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
            "url": "http://example.com/video.mp4",
            "uploadedBy": {
                  "_id": ObjectId("5f3a90110132e115db700201"),
                  "avatar": "default.png",
                  "last_seen": ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                  "name": "A",
                  "status": true,
                  "username": "A"
            },
          },
          {
            "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
            "url": "http://example.com/video.mp4",
            "uploadedBy": {
                  "_id": ObjectId("5f3a90110132e115db700201"),
                  "avatar": "default.png",
                  "last_seen": ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                  "name": "A",
                  "status": true,
                  "username": "A"
            },
          }
        ],
        Downloaded :[
          {
            "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
            "url": "http://example.com/video.mp4",
            "uploadedBy": {
                  "_id": ObjectId("5f3a90110132e115db700201"),
                  "avatar": "default.png",
                  "last_seen": ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                  "name": "A",
                  "status": true,
                  "username": "A"
            },
          },
          {
            "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
            "url": "http://example.com/video.mp4",
            "uploadedBy": {
                  "_id": ObjectId("5f3a90110132e115db700201"),
                  "avatar": "default.png",
                  "last_seen": ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                  "name": "A",
                  "status": true,
                  "username": "A"
            },
          }
        ],
        Liked :[
          {
            "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
            "url": "http://example.com/video.mp4",
            "uploadedBy": {
                  "_id": ObjectId("5f3a90110132e115db700201"),
                  "avatar": "default.png",
                  "last_seen": ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                  "name": "A",
                  "status": true,
                  "username": "A"
            },
          },
          {
            "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
            "url": "http://example.com/video.mp4",
            "uploadedBy": {
                  "_id": ObjectId("5f3a90110132e115db700201"),
                  "avatar": "default.png",
                  "last_seen": ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                  "name": "A",
                  "status": true,
                  "username": "A"
            },
          }
        ],
        Reported :[
          {
            "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
            "url": "http://example.com/video.mp4",
            "uploadedBy": {
                  "_id": ObjectId("5f3a90110132e115db700201"),
                  "avatar": "default.png",
                  "last_seen": ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                  "name": "A",
                  "status": true,
                  "username": "A"
            },
          }
        ],
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Could you please share the structure of HsVideos / FsVideos arrays that you want to get as a result?

Comment: It would be easy with help of some javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is totally a bad structure of schema, you really need to update it, because this will cause memory usage and execution time of the query,

You need to use lookup with pipeline and nested lookup,

- `$match` your conditions for `user`
- `$lookup` with `histories` collection and result will be in `HsVideos`
- `$match` get `histories` of `user_id`
- `$lookup` for `hsVideo` collection and result will be in `hs_videoId`
- `$match` get `hsVideo` details
- `$lookup` with user collection for `updatedBy` and result will be in `updatedBy`
- `$unwind` deconstruct result `updatedBy` and it will be object
- `$unwind` deconstruct `hs_videoId` because its array and we need object
- `$group` by `action` and push required fields in `v` array
- `$project` to show and hide required fields

```
User.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: ObjectId("5f3a90110132e115db700201") } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "histories",
      let: { user_id: "$_id" },
      as: "HsVideos",
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$user_id", "$$user_id"] } } },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "hsVideo",
            let: { hs_videoId: "$hs_videoId" },
            as: "hs_videoId",
            pipeline: [
              { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$hs_videoId", "$_id"] } } },
              {
                $lookup: {
                  from: "user",
                  localField: "uploadedBy",
                  foreignField: "_id",
                  as: "uploadedBy"
                }
              },
              { $unwind: "$uploadedBy" }
            ]
          }
        },
        { $unwind: "$hs_videoId" },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$action",
            v: {
              $push: {
                _id: "$_id",
                url: "$hs_videoId.url",
                name: "$hs_videoId.name",
                uploadedBy: "$hs_videoId.uploadedBy"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        { $project: { _id: 0, k: "$_id", v: 1 } }
      ]
    }
  },
```

- i am repeating the above lines of explanation, repeat the same flow of `HsVideos` in `FsVideos`

```
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "histories",
      let: { user_id: "$_id" },
      as: "FsVideos",
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$user_id", "$$user_id"] } } },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "fsVideo",
            let: { fs_videoId: "$fs_videoId" },
            as: "fs_videoId",
            pipeline: [
              { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$fs_videoId", "$_id"] } } },
              {
                $lookup: {
                  from: "user",
                  localField: "uploadedBy",
                  foreignField: "_id",
                  as: "uploadedBy"
                }
              },
              { $unwind: "$uploadedBy" }
            ]
          }
        },
        { $unwind: "$fs_videoId" },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$action",
            v: {
              $push: {
                _id: "$_id",
                url: "$fs_videoId.url",
                name: "$fs_videoId.name",
                uploadedBy: "$fs_videoId.uploadedBy" 
              }
            }
          }
        },
        { $project: { _id: 0, k: "$_id", v: 1 } }
      ]
    }
  },
```

- $addFields to convert `FsVideos` and `HsVideos` array to object, `action` as key and vlaue

```
  {
    $addFields: { 
      FsVideos: { $arrayToObject: "$FsVideos" },
      HsVideos: { $arrayToObject: "$HsVideos" }
    }
  }
])
.exec(function(err, results){
  if(err) console.log(err);                
  return res.status(200).json(results);
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ACwMQlxbP8b)

Comment: I need Video array with Sub-Array of Action ('downloaded','viewed','liked','reported').

Comment: can you share the structure for that, you can take response from above link and modify as per your need and share.

Comment: please check question, i updated question, Thanks for your help !

Comment: updated answer its done, my suggestion is this is totally a bad idea of schema design, you really need to change it, because it will take more time in execution when lots of data.

Comment: can you please suggest any good approach? Really Appreciate It, thanks a lot....

Comment: i just need to keep user's action history,  how can i achieve that?

Comment: it depends on your project features and usability of videos collection and history collection, i can suggest two options [first](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9pW5q5dpYy6) and [second](https://mongoplayground.net/p/V1MCtL8SKmF) but again it depends on you project features and concept.

Comment: For adding entire document in the $push within a $group stage, you can directly do a $push: $$ROOT @turivishal.

Comment: Thanks @khariSeeng i know that, but OP wants specific fields (id, url, updatedBy), look at the expected result in question.

Comment: @s4suryapal 
Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. please take a look at [how-does-the-bounty-system-work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) and [Bounty Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), no one will get your bounty grace reputation if you not award to anyone. and also it will never reward back to you.

Comment: @ turivishal, thank you for your help! But i am working on changing logic of database design,As you suggested. That's why its delayed. Sorry for delay in reply.

Comment: @s4suryapal its ok, reason behind my comment is just to alert you, bounty points are no more useful for any one else.as per SO rules, i got just half of the bounty and half  because i have 2 votes in answer, and half points are lost, if you think this is helpful answer for your current question then you can award bounty and accept, but now its time gone for award bounty points, if you want to change structure then you can ask new question i will help you with that.

Comment: @turivishal yes i am from Ahmedabad,  its my company. Glad to know you are also from Ahmedabad. Thanks for your help!